# ASP.NET SQL to equal input of a text box

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net

I am currently trying to fill out a table in asp.net and sql. The table needs to fill out according to the Client ID but i am unsure how to do this.

Here is the code with a hard coded value that is drawing into the table. This works. I want to replace the '1004258' with the ClientIDTxt textbox value.

Any ideas and help please?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RCADSCONNECTION %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT CN.ClientID, CN.GivenName1, CN.Surname, CI.DateOfBirth FROM [RioOds].dbo.ClientIndex CI 
                    LEFT JOIN [RioOds].[dbo].[ClientName] CN ON CN.ClientID = CI.ClientID
                    AND CN.AliasType = '1'
                    AND CN.EndDate IS NULL
                    WHERE CN.ClientID = 1004258;"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use paramaters so you would want it to look something like this

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RCADSCONNECTION %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT CN.ClientID, CN.GivenName1, CN.Surname, CI.DateOfBirth FROM [RioOds].dbo.ClientIndex CI 
                    LEFT JOIN [RioOds].[dbo].[ClientName] CN ON CN.ClientID = CI.ClientID
                    AND CN.AliasType = '1'
                    AND CN.EndDate IS NULL
                    WHERE CN.ClientID = @ClientID;"><SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="ClientID" ControlID="ClientIDTxt" PropertyName="Text" />
  </SelectParameters>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters` property. There you can map the id of the text box and the property(`textBox1.Text`) of the `textBox` you want to map to.

Refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selectparameters.aspx) link.

Hope it helps.